# Update preview is not working as expected - Tridion 2013sp1hr1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, experience-manager

Currently facing some interesting behaviour of update preview functionality with XPM.
Post adding components to page XPM service/oData service pushed the data to db n respond back session based filter response.
Updated content is available at page source however update preview is not reflecting changes on page.
Looking for pointers to resolved thus issue.
We are using only one staging website which is enabled with XPM. 
Session preview is in place.
Just thought, may be silly, same page getting edited with same credentials from different browser session break update preview?(Two or more Session Preview ID is getting created for same user is trying to edit the page from different machine (laptops) hence we are facing inconsistent behavior and session is getting locked e.t.)

Thanks ! Hiren Mistry

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on the Tridion Content Manager Stack Exchange site: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15533/update-preview-is-not-working-as-expected-tridion-2013sp1hr1